# How to pandas rows into column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to have a column that's called "Date" and has all the dates that I currently have as rows. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: `.rename_axis('date').reset_index()` ?

Comment: just tried that, but it didn't work. Maybe because I don't have any column named "date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe has the dates as an index, so reset index to pull them out into a column.  If the index was previously named something other than 'index', use that name instead of 'index' if you choose to rename it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2], [4]], columns=['order'])

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'date'})
print(df)
#    date  order
# 0     0      2
# 1     1      4
```

Comment: Terrific.  Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
df = df.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
```